# Finding x values for known y values from a gaussian fit in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have some data that I've fit to a Gaussian of the form:

`y = a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2)`, (the coefficients `a`,`b`,`c` are all known). Unfortunately I can't post an image, but it looks like a standard Gaussian, just with one of the tails not quite dropping down to zero.

What I would like to do is have Matlab determine the `x` values for any `y` value that I specify. Since the fit is Gaussian, there will be two values for nearly every `y` value.

If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: A very naive but straightforward way of doing this is `x(y == y0)`, where `y0` is some fixed y-value.  Or are you looking for an analytic solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve non-linear equation for given y and unknown x. `fsolve` is one way of doing this, but it only returns one solution. You would need to iterate with different starting values. You can also use [newtzero](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6924-newtzero) from file exchange that can find more solutions. This is one example:

```
[a1,b1,c1] = deal(2, 3, 4);
[a2,b2,c2] = deal(2, 3, 4);


yValue  = 3; % example of known y value

f = @(x) a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1).^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2).^2) - yValue ;



x =  newtzero(f, [0]); % search for roots of f function



xT = linspace(-20, 20, 100); 
yT = arrayfun(f, xT);

figure, plot(xT, yT, '-'); hold on; grid on;
plot(xT, zeros(1, numel(xT)), 'k-');

% plot found roots
plot(x, zeros(1, numel(x)), 'ro');
```

[image]